# Joomla 4 URL processing/routing

Tags: joomla-4, router

I have a Joomla extension running on 3.10 which fails on Joomla 4. The issue is that it generates URLs of the form /index.php?option=COMPONENT&view=VIEW&task=TASK&parameter=PARAM which generates a 404 error on J4. I've looked all over the place and can't find anything definitive on these questions

1. Is there a way to configure J4 to accept this form of URL
2. If not, what do I need to do to the extension to change it to work on J4

I looked at com_content (which will work with this form of URL) but got lost navigating it.

Comment: Normally, non-SEF URLs should not produce 404 errors (assuming the parameters are correct). Impossible to tell without seeing the code. How is the router implemented?

Answer (score 1):

There are some backward compatibility issues in Joomla 4 when using Joomla 3 code: https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4

Furthermore are you sure that the 404 errors are caused by the URL structure?

I suspect that there is other code in your component that triggers the error. **With a good IDE** (like the commercial PHPStorm, or Visual Studio or Netbeans) **in combination with Xdebug** you can step through the code and see all variables and their values in each step. That way you can analyze where/why the Joomla 3 component is not working.

Comment: The reason I think it's the URL is the stack trace from Joomla debug mode. It's all in the Application and Router, with Router at the top  JROOT/libraries/src/Router/Router.php:153

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that somewhere in the processing, an href with a relative pathname is handled differently between Joomla 3 and Joomla 4. In Joomla 3, the base site URL is prepended. In Joomla 4, a menu item is prepended (probably the current menu item), which causes it to fail in some cases.
In the case I described, the URL was a relative pathname generated within javascript.
There are several solutions possible. One is to write a router to handle it. A quicker solution is to generate a full pathname including a correct menu item. The Joomla Uri::base method will get the base site URL. Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->route will give you the menu item subpath.

Comment: Does this question provide resolving advice?  If not, then it is Not An Answer.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your advice.  Might you [edit] this answer to clarify the advice that you are offering about how to resolve the question?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to resolve this.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue. Thanks for the pointers; I'm still having a hard time figuruing out where I need to apply those changes you mention, though - is it something in the router.php I have to adapt? Do you maybe have links to a good resource on how routing is supposed to be implemented in J4 components (or just a simple, working example - can't figure out how it's working in the included components with all the service stuff)?

Comment: As it turns out, for me I think the error came from not clearing out the in/out `$segments` parameter in the router's parse method (solution to that inspired by another component). Maybe a joomla bug...